# Apache Spark: class registration order in Kryo

Tags: apache-spark, kryo

According to the Kryo documentation classes registered in Kryo should have the same identifiers assigned during serialization and deserialization

https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo#registration
"During deserialization, the registered classes must have the exact same IDs they had during serialization"

As far as I know classes registered internally by spark and classes registered using method sparkConf.registerKryoClasses have identifiers assigned automatically according to registration order so any change in this registration order could break possibility of deserialization.

Please, help me understand how this issue is handled in Apache Spark?

Answer (score 1):

From the *Kryo* documentation:

> During deserialization, the registered classes must have the exact same IDs they had during serialization. The register method shown above assigns the next available, lowest integer ID, which means the order classes are registered is important.

In other words to have the same ID when de-serializing you need to have all the classes to be registered always in the same order. The order of registration is **stable** in Spark.

You just need to make sure you will register custom classes using `sparkConf.registerKryoClasses()` always in stable order.

You can check the order of class registration in the Spark source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/serializer/KryoSerializer.scala#L82).

Answer (score 0):

As you said order of classes is stable for version but in case of upgrade, amount and order of registered classes will be different

Comment: When you upgrade Spark, you will upgrade it at all nodes of the cluster - all the worker nodes will run the same version of Spark. The order of class registration can change, but will be stable again across the cluster.